# Need to decompile executable from Openwrt ELF 32-bit

Tags: decompile, decompiler

what best tool to use to decompile executable from Openwrt image
ELF 32-bit MSB executable, MIPS, MIPS32 rel2 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-uClibc.so.0, no section header ?
binnary file I have in my GIT repo if anybody want a quick look:
https://github.com/Egyras/MyOpenhab/blob/master/a2wmain

Comment: what does `file` command say?

Comment: Got such info from:
Program Name: a2wmain
Language ID: MIPS:BE:32:default (1.5)
Compiler ID: default
Processor: MIPS

Comment: @IgorSkochinsky  what you think ?

Comment: @IgorSkochinsky here is output: 
/tmp/ssl/a2wmain: ELF 32-bit MSB executable, MIPS, MIPS32 rel2 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-uClibc.so.0, no section header

Comment: Add it to the question, maybe someone will have an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your binary contains MIPS-16e code. I will be adding support for this ISA to the [Reko](https://github.com/uxmal/reko) decompiler this week. You can follow the progress [here](https://github.com/uxmal/reko/issues/833).

Comment: Give me a week first, to get the decoder working  :)

Comment: But in Reko GIT release I cant find fresh version ? When its planned ?

Comment: The MIPS-16e disassembler is complete. You can get Reko from the CI releases at https://ci.appveyor.com/project/uxmal/reko/build/artifacts. I suggest continuing this thread over on https://github.com/uxmal/reko/issues